# Rake Defining a Route that is just :id versus :group_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :groups do
    get 'settings'
  end
```

**Rake Routes:**

```
group_settings GET    /groups/:group_id/settings(.:format)                                                              {:controller=>"groups", :action=>"settings"}
```

Problem is I want it to be :id not :group_id

Any suggestions on how to make that happen? Did I define the routes incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting it as a `member` of the resources block to correctly scope the `:id` parameter:

```
resources :groups do
  member do
    get 'settings'
  end
end
```

Comment: Very well done. Thanks. I hadn't used the member before in the routes file.

Comment: Rails Guides have a great breakdown of Rails 3 routing (as well as just about every other aspect of the framework) -  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html. Super good resource.